# Unable to get escape characters when a system path is passed as argument to a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I my program I have to pass the path of a video file, so that the function reads the passed argument and plays the file. But whats happening is, If I give path "G:\sun\play.wmv", after parsing it is taking as "G:sunplay.wmv"

In .cpp file I wrote this code:

```
int main(void)
{
  VideoPlayer h;

  h.Load("G:\Sunny Cpp-2\edit.wmv");
  h.Start();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

The header file used is user defined and function in it is:

```
bool VideoPlayer::Load(const char* pFilePath)
{
   //internal coding
}
```

Now in the argument pFilePath the value is "G:Sunny Cpp-2edit.wmv". So the function is unable to read path from system. What modification should be made to make it work?
Any help is accepted. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: You haven't used any escape characters at all. In fact, that is the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Symbol '\' denotes simple escape sequence as for example the new line character '\n' or quote '\"'. To distinguish an escape sequence from character '\' the last has to be doubled as '\'

Write

```
"G:\\Sunny Cpp-2\\edit.wmv"
```

instead of

```
"G:\Sunny Cpp-2\edit.wmv"
```

Or use a raw string literal

```
R"(G:\Sunny Cpp-2\edit.wmv)"
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>

void f( const char *s ) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

int main() 
{
    f( "G:\\Sunny Cpp-2\\edit.wmv" );
    f( R"(G:\Sunny Cpp-2\edit.wmv)" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
G:\Sunny Cpp-2\edit.wmv
G:\Sunny Cpp-2\edit.wmv
```

Comment: I think raw string literals only exist in C++11 or later. If you're not using that, use the other solution instead.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008, can you suggest me for that @GeorgeT

Comment: @user3615925 See my post. There is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a special character. It is used to give special meaning of other characters like `\n` ( it gives 'n' special meaning, the combination is treated as newline). So if you want to use '\' without *special meaning* you have to specialize if by using another '\'. So use `"G:\\Sunny Cpp-2\\edit.wmv"`.